# How to attach some Model variable as part of @Url.Content in ASP .NET MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The `@photo.Image` has an image name.

How to attach some Model variable as part of `@Url.Content` path in ASP .NET MVC 3?

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/images/????)"> @photo.Title</a>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just simply concat the photo.Image to the path.

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/images/" + photo.Image)'> @photo.Title</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacement:

```
    function GetTabInfo(controllerAction, clientInfoid, stepId) 
    {
       alert(controllerAction);

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/xxx")/?clientInfoid=' + clientInfoid + '&stepId=' + stepId;

        url = url.replace("xxx", controllerAction);

        alert(url);

         $.get(url, null, function (result) {

            //                alert(result);

          $(targetDiv).html(result);

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This way u can concatenate Variable with strings.

```
 src="@Url.Content( "~/Images/"+Model.Pic)"
```